# define expression in camunda

Tags: camunda, camunda-plugin, camunda-spin

I have a process that has a custom model, similar to the following model(get by calling `http://localhost:8080/engine-rest/task/{id}/variables/`):

```
{
    "Title": {
        "type": "String",
        "value": "aaa",
        "valueInfo": {
          
        }
      },
    "247f3af4-36cf-72cc-1a95-601f07640674": {
        "type": "String",
        "value": "{\"Title\":\"AA\",\"Value\":\"BB\"}",
        "valueInfo": {
      
        }
    }
}
```

I want to define a expressions at the gates. How should I do this?

I try these:

```
${ "247f3af4-36cf-72cc-1a95-601f07640674".Value == "AA"}
```

Or

```
${ JSON("247f3af4-36cf-72cc-1a95-601f07640674").prop("Value") == "AA"}
```

Or

```
${S(247f3af4-36cf-72cc-1a95-601f07640674).prop("Value").stringValue() == "AA"}
```

But get following errors:

```
Unknown property used in expression: ${ "247f3af4-36cf-72cc-1a95-601f07640674".Value == "AA"}. Cause: Could not find property Value in class java.lang.String
```

```
Error while evaluating expression: ${ JSON("247f3af4-36cf-72cc-1a95-601f07640674").prop("Value") == "AA"}. Cause: Error invoking function 'JSON'
```

```
ENGINE-01009 Error while parsing process. Error parsing '${S(247f3af4-36cf-72cc-1a95-601f07640674).prop("Value").stringValue() == "AA"}': syntax error at position 15, encountered 'c7', expected ')'.
```

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I finally find answer
I must use something like this:

```
${S(a247f3af4_36cf_72cc_1a95_601f07640674).prop("Value").stringValue() == "AA"}
```

we must start variable name with character and do'nt use `-`.

Answer (score 1):

What you are showing is the value of a JSON object stored in a process data, right? What is the name of the process data?

In Java you use JSON(), in the process (JavaScript) use S()
(see https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.17/reference/spin/json/01-reading-json/)

Place S() around the name of your process data to create the object. Then you can use .prop() to navigate it.  ${S(myData).prop("xyz")}.

In this example I used the method to read the JSON response of a REST call and then extract a field:

https://github.com/rob2universe/camunda-http-connector-example

You use JSON() around the name of the process data, then you can access the properties

Comment: yes this is the value of a JSON object stored in a process data and get it by calling  `http://localhost:8080/engine-rest/task/{id}/variables/`.  But what is the `name of your process data` ?

Comment: please see this image : https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cn3lJ.png

Comment: The {id} you use when using: ttp://localhost:8080/engine-rest/task/{id}/variables/.
Under which identifier to you store the data?